# What is the difference between LogicApp.json and LogicApp.definition.json templates?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created same Logic App locally on visual studio code and visual code community. I found that both created different template files i.e. LogicApp.json on VS Community and LogicApp.definition.json on VS Code. What make these template files different from each other?

Json from VS Community (LogicApp.json):-

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "logicAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 80,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Logic App."
      }
    },
    "logicAppLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "allowedValues": [
        "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "eastasia",
        "southeastasia",
        "centralus",
        "eastus",
        "eastus2",
        "westus",
        "northcentralus",
        "southcentralus",
        "northeurope",
        "westeurope",
        "japanwest",
        "japaneast",
        "brazilsouth",
        "australiaeast",
        "australiasoutheast",
        "southindia",
        "centralindia",
        "westindia",
        "canadacentral",
        "canadaeast",
        "uksouth",
        "ukwest",
        "westcentralus",
        "westus2",
        "koreacentral",
        "koreasouth",
        "francecentral",
        "francesouth",
        "uaecentral",
        "uaenorth",
        "southafricanorth",
        "southafricawest",
        "switzerlandnorth",
        "switzerlandwest",
        "germanynorth",
        "germanywestcentral",
        "norwayeast",
        "brazilsoutheast"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location of the Logic App."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('logicAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "location": "[parameters('logicAppLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "LogicApp"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "actions": {
            "Response": {
              "type": "Response",
              "kind": "http",
              "inputs": {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "body": "hello user!"
              },
              "runAfter": {}
            }
          },
          "parameters": {},
          "triggers": {
            "manual": {
              "type": "Request",
              "kind": "Http",
              "inputs": {
                "schema": {},
                "method": "GET"
              }
            }
          },
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "outputs": {}
        },
        "parameters": {}
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Json from VS Code (LoginApp.definition.json):-

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "workflows_logic_vscode_name": {
            "defaultValue": "logic-vscode",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "location": "eastus",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_logic_vscode_name')]",
            "properties": {
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "triggers": {
                        "Request": {
                            "type": "Request",
                            "kind": "Http",
                            "inputs": {
                                "method": "GET",
                                "schema": {}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "Response": {
                            "runAfter": {},
                            "type": "Response",
                            "inputs": {
                                "body": "Hello user",
                                "statusCode": 200
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {},
                "state": "Enabled"
            },
            "scale": null,
            "tags": {},
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"
        }
    ],
    "variables": {}
}
```

Comment: I don't have those files, could you add the JSON to the question?

Comment: @juunas Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Both are workflow definitions, when you check in details the workflow looks similar but the format is different.

Formats will get differs when the creation done in VS-Code/Visual Studio/Portal/etc..

Below is the sample definition how it looks when we create it from Azure Portal:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/XXXX-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {},
        "contentVersion": "X.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Have a look on the difference in creation of logic app in [VSCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-logic-apps-visual-studio-code#:%7E:text=In%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%2C%20under%20Logic%20Apps%2C%20open,new%20resource%20group%20or%20an%20existing%20resource%20group.) and [VisualStudio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-logic-apps-with-visual-studio) and its workflow from Microsoft documentation.